# Recursive algorithm getting all combinations into two groups

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, combinations, permutation

I need an algorithm that, given an even number of elements, performs an evaluation on all combinations of the elements divided into two groups. Order within a group doesn't matter and so permutations within groups shouldn't be repeated. An example with N=4 elements would be the evaluations

```
e(12,34), e(13,24), e(14,32), e(32,14), e(34,12), e(24,13)
```

I thought I had it, with a recursive algorithm that works up to N=6, but it turns out it fails for N=8. This is the algorithm (this version just prints out the two groups; in my actual implementation it will perform a calculation):

```
// Class for testing algoritm
class sym {

    private:
    int N, Nhalf, combs;
    VI order;
    void evaluate();
    void flip(int, int);
    void combinations(int, int);

    public:
    void combinations();

    sym(int N_) : N(N_) {
        if(N%2) {
           cout "Number of particles must divide the 2 groups; requested N = " << N << endl;
           throw exception();
        }
        Nhalf=N/2;
        order.resize(N);
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) order[i]=i+1;  
    }

    ~sym() {
        cout << endl << combs << " combinations" << endl << endl;
    }
};

// Swaps element n in group 1 and i in group 2
void sym::flip(int n, int i) {
    int tmp=order[n];
    order[n]=order[i+Nhalf];
    order[i+Nhalf]=tmp;
}

// Evaluation (just prints the two groups)
void sym::evaluate() {
    for(int i=0;i<Nhalf;i++) cout << order[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=Nhalf;i<N;i++) cout << order[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << "--------------------" << endl;
    combs++;
}

// Starts the algorithm
void sym::combinations() {
    cout << "--------------------" << endl;
    combinations(0, 0);
} 

// Recursive algorithm for the combinations
void sym::combinations(int n, int k) {
    if(n==Nhalf-1) {
        evaluate();
        for(int i=k;i<Nhalf;i++) {
            flip(n, i);
            evaluate();
            flip(n, i);
        }
        return;
    }
    combinations(n+1, k);
    for(int i=k;i<Nhalf;i++) {
        flip(n, i);
        combinations(n+1, k+i+1);
        flip(n, i);
    }
}
```

If I run this with N=2 for example, I get the correct

```
--------------------
1 2 
3 4 
--------------------
1 3 
2 4 
--------------------
1 4 
3 2 
--------------------
3 2 
1 4 
--------------------
3 4 
1 2 
--------------------
4 2 
3 1 
--------------------

6 combinations
```

But it seems N>6 doesn't work. Is there a simple change that will fix this, or will I have to rethink the whole thing?

EDIT: It is better if every change just involves swapping two elements (like the failed attempt above); as this will make the code faster in the end I think.

EDIT: Just realised it fails for N=6 as well, sloppy testing.

Comment: Thinking about it as two groups just creates extra effort.  It is much simpler if you view the goal as creating a subset exactly half the size of the original set (then the other group is everything not in that subset).

Comment: That's true. The only ways I've manages to do that though involve more than just swaps between elements (see last edit). But I'm sure there's a way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// generate all combination that use n of the numbers 1..k
void sym::combinations(int n, int k) {
   if (n>k) return;  // oops
   if (n==0) { evaluate(); return; }
   combinations(n, k-1);
   order[n-1] = k;
   combinations(n-1,k-1);
}
```

Start that with `combinations(N/2,N)` No need to pre initialize `order`.  But as coded it only fills the first half of `order` with the first group and you need to post process to get the second group.

With a moderate amount of extra logic, you could instead fill in the second half during `combinations`.  I think this does it:

```
void sym::combinations(int n, int k) {
   if (k==0) { evaluate(); return; }
   if (n>0) {
       order[n-1] = k;
       combinations(n-1,k-1); }
   if (n<k) {
       order[Nhalf+k-n-1] = k;
       combinations(n, k-1); }
}
```

I think a flip based design is uglier.  But after more thought, it isn't actually difficult.  So changing back to your design of starting at `combinations(0,0)` you could use:

```
// Generate all combinations subject to having already filled the first n
// of the first group and having already filled the last k of the second.
void sym::combinations(int n, int k) {
    if(n==Nhalf) {
        // Once the first group is full, the rest must be the second group
        evaluate();
        return; 
    }
    // Since the first group isn't full, recursively get all combinations
    // That make the current order[n] part of the first group
    combinations(n+1,k);

    if (k<Nhalf) {
      // Next try all combinations that make the current order[n] part of
      // the second group
      std::swap(order[n], order[N-k-1]);
      combinations(n,k+1);
      // Since no one cares about the sequence of the items not yet chosen
      // there is no benefit to swapping back.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::next_permutation` may help (without recursion):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void do_job(const std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<std::size_t>& groups)
{
    std::cout << " e(";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if (groups[i] == 0) {
            std::cout << " " << v[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << ",";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if (groups[i] == 1) {
            std::cout << " " << v[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << ")\n";
}

template<typename T>
void print_combinations(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> groups(v.size() / 2, 0);
    groups.resize(v.size(), 1); // groups is now {0, .., 0, 1, .., 1}

    do {
        do_job(v, groups);
    } while (std::next_permutation(groups.begin(), groups.end()));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    print_combinations(numbers);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/D2gphQ)

Answer (score 1):

To recursively list the `n choose n/2` combinations you could use an algorithm that adds each value to either group:

```
f(n,k,A,B):
  if k == 0:
    output A,B with {n,n-1..1}
  else if n == k:
    output A with {n,n-1..1},B
  else if k > 0:
    f(n-1,k-1,A with n,B)
    f(n-1,k,A,B with n)
```

Example below. To half the accumulating stack, one could skip one of the two first recursive calls and reverse the order of the pair during evaluation.

```
f(4,2,[],[])
  f(3,1,[4],[])
    f(2,0,[4,3],[]) => {[4,3],[2,1]}
    f(2,1,[4],[3])
      f(1,0,[4,2],[3]) => {[4,2],[3,1]}
      f(1,1,[4],[3,2]) => {[4,1],[3,2]}
  f(3,2,[],[4])
    f(2,1,[3],[4])
      f(1,0,[3,2],[4]) => {[3,2],[4,1]}
      f(1,1,[3],[4,2]) => {[3,1],[4,2]}
    f(2,2,[],[4,3]) => {[2,1],[4,3]}
```